# create-react-app issue with IIS hosting and IE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, iis, create-react-app

I am trying to set up a react application that I have created based on the React Create App template, however I am getting issues when hosting using IIS.

The main page (index.html) appears to load correctly, however the compiled JS appears to fail to load correctly.

I am trying to load the page using IE and as you can see in the image below my non-compiled JS file appears to load correctly, however the compiled JS and CSS seems to fail to load, even though I can confirm that those files exist and with the correct names.

[image]

The site is a static site with React Route in use, though the root index.html should serve up a default page.

Comment: Your compiled JS and CSS isn't loading at all.  Check the `static` folder on your server: anything actually in there?  You need to check your build process, however you've set that up.  If you want an answer here, you'll have to supply more information than you have; e.g. your build process (Webpack?) config would be a good start.

Comment: @ChillyPenguin assets are there, the issue was as Abdeslem described, its now resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before running `npm run build` you need to set a hostname in your `package.json`. Add this line to the top of your package.json, assuming that your build will be hosted on the root folder of your web server:

```
"homepage":"http://localhost",
```

Your folder structure on the web server will look something like this:

```
public_html <----- assuming this is your root folder on the web server
   |
   |----index.html
   |
   |-----static
           |
           |----css
           |----js
```